# Change admin route /admin to /adminarea nopcommerce

Tags: asp.net, security, asp.net-mvc-5, nopcommerce

Change admin route **/admin** to **/adminarea** nopcommerce 
I search in **Infrastructure/RouteProvider.cs** about admin route but not found any thing !

*And I want to IgnoreRoute to /admin*

Comment: What you have tried so far, show your code!

Comment: Check the AdminAreaRegistration class

Comment: @DivyangDesai I search about the file to change the route ..

Comment: @Raphael `public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
        {
            context.MapRoute(
                "Admin_default",
                "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", area = "Admin", id = "" },
                new[] { "Nop.Admin.Controllers" }
            );
        }`

Comment: I change **Admin** to **Adminarea**  but it isn't apply

Comment: Changing Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id} should do the trick. But be careful, there are other hardcoded "/admin" usage. You will have to update them too

Comment: @Raphael Where're the other files I must update?

Comment: Just do search for "/admin" or "admin" and check the results.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the adminarea code but it may cause some errors if you don't check every where that admin area rout called, i think its a big change so try to create a route and redirect users to admin or something like this.
Changing adkin area route in code with no even knows where to do that simply,will cause some problems on other sides of application